# Mapping a std::tuple to another std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's assume I have a `std::tuple<Types...>`, I want to generate a `std::tuple<std::priority_queue<Types...>>`

```
#include <queue>
#include <tuple>

template<typename TypesTuple>
struct Bar {
    std::priority_queue<std::for_each_tuple_type(TypesTuple)...> queues;
};

using Foo = Bar<std::tuple<int, double>>;
```

How can that be achieved?

**EDIT**

Could it get easier with boost::tuple or vector and transform? Can transform be applied on the meta level?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Given a `tuple<int, double>`, you're saying you want a `tuple<priority_queue<int, double>>`. That's not a thing. Or do you want a `tuple<priority_queue<int>, priority_queue<double>>`? Or a `priority_queue<tuple<int, double>>`?

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? These seems weird.

Comment: I want to create a heterogeneous priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial specialization:

```
template<typename TypesTuple>
struct Bar;

template<typename... Ts>
struct Bar<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    std::tuple<std::priority_queue<Ts>...> queues;
};
```

So `my_bar.queue` will be of type `std::tuple<std::priority_queue<int>, std::priority_queue<double>>`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e40b9ed6cacf3e0)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
template<class... Types>
std::tuple<std::priority_queue<Types...>> convert(std::tuple<Types...>);

using Foo = decltype(convert(std::declval<std::tuple<int>>());
```

However, that only works if the tuple contains 1 to 3 elements and they satisfy [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) template argument requirements, e.g.:

```
using Foo = decltype(convert( std::declval<std::tuple<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int> > >() ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class In, template<class...>class Map>
struct template_map;
template<class In, template<class...>class Map>
using template_map_t=typename template_map<In, Map>::type;

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts, template<class...>class Map>
struct template_map<Z<Ts...>, Map> {
  using type=Z<Map<Ts>...>;
};
```

This takes a type that is a template over types, and a type map, and returns the type after you map the enclosed types by the map.

```
template<typename TypesTuple>
struct Bar {
  template_map_t<TypesTuple, std::priority_queue> queues;
};

using Foo = Bar<std::tuple<int, double>>;
```

Writing `template_map_t` can be done in many ways.

---

While I wouldn't advise it, here is a hana-style:

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{ constexpr tag_t() {}; using type=T; };
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<template<class...>class Z>
struct ztemplate_t{
  constexpr ztemplate_t() {};
  template<class...Ts>using apply=Z<Ts...>;
};
template<template<class...>class Z>
constexpr ztemplate_t<Z> ztemplate{};
```

These are constexpr values which store types and templates respectively.

```
template<class Z, class...Ts>
constexpr auto zapply( Z, tag_t<Ts>... )
-> tag_t< typename Z::template apply<Ts...> >
{ return {}; }
```

`zapply` now lets us use values to apply templates to types.

We can now write a map function:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts, class zM>
constexpr auto zmap( tag_t<Z<Ts...>>, zM )
{ return zapply( ztemplate<Z>, zapply( zM{}, tag<Ts> )... ); }
```

and extract the type:

```
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<typename TypesTuple>
struct Bar {
  using queues_t = type_t<decltype(
    zmap( tag<TypesTuple>, ztemplate<std::priority_queue> )
  )>;
  queues_t queues;
};
```

with test code:

```
using Foo = Bar<std::tuple<int, double>>;

tag_t< std::tuple< std::priority_queue<int>, std::priority_queue<double> > > test = tag< decltype( std::declval<Foo&>().queues ) >;
```

which shows the type map worked.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c5d36340df2dafe).

Comment: @user3612643 Nothing, but writing a hana-style metaprogramming system (using types and values to do metaprogramming) for such a simple problem seems like a bad idea.